# Unforttunately app has stopped

Tags: android-fragment, navigation-drawer

Estoy tratando de desarrollar una app partiendo de la plantilla que Navigation Drawer que trae Android Studio.

Creo todos los fragments y los ubico en la opción correspondiente del menu, la MainActivity no muestra ningún error de sintaxis, pero en la ejecución cuando voy a seleccionar uno me devuelve el error siguiente:

> Unfortunately  has stopped. OK.

Dejo el código de MainActivity.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        Fragment mi_fragment = null;
        boolean fragmentseleccionado = false;

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
            mi_fragment = new HistoriaFragment();
            fragmentseleccionado = true;

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {
            mi_fragment = new QuienesSomosFragment();
            fragmentseleccionado = true;

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {
            mi_fragment = new ContactosFragment();
            fragmentseleccionado = true;

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        if (fragmentseleccionado == true) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, mi_fragment).commit();
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

Mi API es la 28, por lo que pienso no debo implentar  Fragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener.
Espero por su ayuda
Gracias

Answer (score 0):

El problema lo resolví implementando OnFragmentInteractionListener para cada fragment en el MainActivity.

Gracias

Comment: algún fragment de código de ejemplo que puedas usar para complementar tu respuesta?